# Spring form:radiobutton(s) having one selected on page load

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc

```
<form:form method="post" action="/changeEnabledResource" modelAttribute="user">
    <c:forEach items="${user.resources}" var="resource">
        <form:radiobutton path="resources" 
                          value="${resource}" 
                          label="${resource.name}" 
                          checked="${resource.enabled ? 'checked' : ''}/>
    </c:forEach>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Resource class:

```
public class Resource {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private boolean enabled;

    //getters setters
}
```

User class:

```
public class User {
    private List<Resource> resources;
    ....
    //rest of code
}
```

With the above code all form:radiobuttons have checked="checked", so the last one is always checked when the form loads. Submitting works correctly and it changes the correct one to enabled and the rest to not enabled (service class handles this). But when the page loads all radio buttons have checked="checked".

Why is this happening, or what would be the correct way to do this so that the resource that IS enabled has the radio button checked?

Comment: I was checking the syntax and seems correct, did you check if the list of resources is returning the correct values? not everything true?

Comment: Ok, so if the value="${resource}" then the HTML rendered sets that to the resource id and results in the issue above. If I set value="${resource.enabled}", then the issue is resolved, BUT when I submit, the user object's resources are null which breaks the whole functionality.

Comment: It looks like when I set the value to ${resource.enabled} there is a binding error: nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'false'; 
nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "false"]

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is to NOT use the form:radiobutton(s) tags since they apparently don't work very well. I have yet to find any **good** examples anywhere using this tag. My solution was just to use plain HTML input tags and use the @RequestParam in the controller method which will pass only the value of the radio button that is checked. And I can easily use ${resource.enabled ? 'checked' : ''} to ensure that the correct one is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Set the selected value in a separate property:

```
public class User {
    private int selectedResourceId;
    private List<Resource> resources;
    ....
    //rest of code
}


...
<form:radiobutton path="selectedResourceId" 
                  value="${resource.id}" 
                  label="${resource.name}"/>
...
```

On page load, initalize the `selectedResourceId` (based on the `resource` where `enabled` flag is `true`), so that the `form:radiobutton` tag knows which one is selected when the page is rendered.

Upon form submission, go in the other direction and set the appropriate `resource.enabled` flag based on the `selectedResourceId`.